# how to compare two boolean lists

Tags: python, function, boolean, analytics

For Python: I need to write  two functions that satisfy this question

Problem 5. Suppose 10 patients numbered 0 through 9 are participating in a trial of a new Covid Test.
Through other means, it is known whether each patient actually has covid. This information is recorded in a list called HasCovid of 10 elements. HasCovid = [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False].
Once the new test is given to each of patients you know which of them has tested positive. This is indicated by a list of test results called TestsPositive = [True, False, True, False, True, True, False,True,False, True]
A patient is a True Positive if they have tested positive and they do indeed have Covid. A patient is a False Positive if they test positive but are known not to have covid.
Write a function num_TP which counts the number of true positives and another called num_FP which counts the number of false positives. This is a specific example of 10 patients. Your code should work for any such pair of Boolean lists, both with 10 elements.

Comment: Please provide some more information. How is your data stored, in a pandas dataframe? list? dictionary? The answers may vary depending on this.

Comment: Information is stored in the two lists above: HasCovid and TestsPositive.

Comment: Please have a read through my answers, test out for yourself and if required, request some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this presuming you have the data available in a Dataframe already.

It would look like this:

```py
>>> df
   TestsPositive IsPositive
0     True    False
1     True    True
...etc
```

You can utilise pandas summary techniques

```py
>>> ((df['TestsPositive'] == True) & (df['IsPositive'] == True)).sum()
1
```

Comment: Apologies, I've just seen your response. But perhaps this will still help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option here, you create a function that passes in both lists, and uses the index of each list to reference each other.

The key here is to use the enumerate function to create the index number

```py
def false_positive(test_result, actual_status):
    false_positives = 0
    for i,test in enumerate(test_result):
        # count false positives
        if test == True:
            if test != actual_status[i]:
                false_positives += 1
    return false_positives
```

I think that's more along the lines you're looking for.

Comment: This one worked for me and was able to modify it to fit the other part of the question by removing the not equals part. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: you're welcome, and dont forget to market as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use the bucle `for`, you can do with function `map`, it's easier and it's more recommended.
It would look something like this

```
def num_TP(hasCovid,tests):
    mergedLists = zip(hasCovid,tests)

    mergedLists = map(lambda x:x[0] and x[1],mergedLists)

    return  list(mergedLists).count(True)
    

def num_FP(hasCovid,tests):
    mergedLists = zip(hasCovid,tests) 

    mergedLists = map(lambda x: x[0] != x[1] ),mergedLists)
    
    return list(mergedLists).count(True)
```

If you've some questions i recommend this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) or ask me, maybe i can answer you.

Sorry for my english i'm not native.